# VBA Macro Error: "Run-Time error 1004: The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type"

Tags: excel, vba, dimension

I have three Excel sheets. The first ('Player Internal') tab has a dropdown menu that toggles through Player #1-4, and each Player has a specific ID - Player 1 is 201, Player 2 is 202, Player 3 is 203, and Player 4 is 204. The sheet contains a lot of data formatted into tables - data that are being pulled in using Joiner IDs I created using each Player ID. So for example, to pull in the number of games won for each player, I have a joiner for Player 1 that is 201_Game1Wins. One note too - there are two years of data (2020 and 2021).

The second sheet ('Player Public Report') pulls in data from 'Player Internal' - this is done using the XLOOKUP function. I'm able to toggle through Players 1-4 using the dropdown in 'Player Internal' and the data flow into the tables in 'Player Public Report').

Lastly, I have a sheet ('Player Cross Data') that is supposed to house the results of my Macro ('CrossPlayerDataPull') - I want to see just one table that pulls in the data for each of the players.

My Macro is written so that it toggles through Players 1-4 in the 'Player Internal' tab, the data flows through to 'Player Public Report' tab, and then the Player-specific data for each year are copied and pasted into this single table that I am trying to create.

The Macro runs so that only Player's data for 2020 and 2021 get populated, but then the Macro stops and I get an Error, with one of my 'Range' line codes highlighted (*I identified it below - - it is within my "CopyDataIns sub") and I don't know what's wrong.

My code is below:

```
Sub PlayerRun()
    CrossPlayerDataPull
    
End Sub

'switching Player IDs
Sub PlayerSwap(PlayerID As Integer, PlayerName As String)
     Dim downdownIDlocation As String
    dropdownIDLocation = "'Player Internal'!E2"

'this is where you swap the tables

    Range(dropdownIDLocation) = PlayeRID
    CopyDataIns "IndPlayerTarget[TME Growth]", "CrossPlayerTarget[" & PlayerName & "]"
    CopyDataIns "IndPlayerAttributedLives[2021]", "CrossPlayerAttributedLives[" & PlayerName & "]"

    CopyDataIns "IndPlayerNPI[2020]", "CrossPayerNPI[" & PlayerName & " 2020]"
    CopyDataIns "IndPlayerNPI[2021]", "CrossPayerNPI[" & PlayerName & " 2021]"
    CopyDataIns "IndPlayerNPICollapsed[2010]", "CrossPlayerNPICollapsed[" & PlayerName & " 2020]"
    CopyDataIns "IndPlayerNPICollapsed[2021]", "CrossPlayerNPICollapsed[" & PlayerName & " 2021]"
    
    CopyDataIns "IndPlayerAggSpendLOB[2021]", "CrossPlayerAggSpendLOB[" & PlayerName & "]"

    CopyDataIns "IndPlayerPayerMix[2021]", "CrossPlayerPayerMix[" & PlayerName & "]"
    CopyDataIns "IndPlayerServiceCat[Commercial]", "CrossPlayerServiceCatComm[" & PlayerName & "]"
    CopyDataIns "IndPlayerServiceCat[Medicare Managed Care]", "CrossPlayerServiceCatMedicare[" & PlayerName & "]"
    CopyDataIns "IndPayerServiceCat[Medicaid Managed Care]", "CrossPlayerServiceCatMedicaid[" & PlayerName & "]"

  End Sub
    
'this is where i define CopyDataIns it is saying to copy whatever is within
'CopyDataIns for my two categories to be stored as text strings
Sub CopyDataIns(PlayerIndividualData As String, PlayerCombinedData As String)
'Select player public report tab then then go into the IndPayerTarget sheet and
'copyplayer performance
    Sheets("Player Public Report").Select
**  ***Range(PlayerIndividualData).Select*** <- THIS IS WHAT THE DEBUGGER FLAGS**
    Selection.Copy
    
    'Select analysis tab of all player and then go to the appropriate player and paste values
    Sheets("Player Cross Analyses").Select

    Range(PlayerCombinedData).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub


Sub CrossPlayerDataPull()
    Dim downdownIDlocation As String
    dropdownIDLocation = "'Player Internal Analyses'!E2"
    
    'Store dropdown lookup as text
    Dim originalData As String
   
    originalData = Range(dropdownIDLocation).Formula2R1C1
    
    'change drop down locations based on Players

    InsurerSwap 201, "Player1"
    InsurerSwap 202, "Player2"
    InsurerSwap 203, "Player3"
    InsurerSwap 204, "Player4"
    
    'Reset dropdown to stored text
    'Range(dropdownIDLocation) = originalData
    
End Sub
```

I tried to manually do the copying and pasting in a recorded Macro to see what it produced, but I wasn't able to identify the issue that way either.

Comment: `Dim downdownIDlocation As String` ?? shouldn't that be `dropdownIDLocation`. Do you have charts linked to the tables ? Is so what type ?

Comment: @CDP1802 good catch, corrected to the right name. Yes, I have a clustered column linked to this table.

Comment: `IndPlayerNPICollapsed[2010]` ?? 2010

Comment: @CDP1802 *facepalm* that should've been 2020, and correcting that allowed the Macro to run all the way through! thank you so much. While the Macro runs completely, I still get that error. do you know why?

Comment: Is the chart range set by some VBA (like an onChange event) or is it static ?

Comment: @CDP1802 It is static, not set by VBA.